# Using Scrutor for Register interface assembly

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, scrutor

I'm using Scrutor 8.1 to register all types in my assembly that implement interfaces (ASP.NET Core 6).

I have a code structure similar to the following (all type members omitted for brevity):

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
```

I use this code in `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.Scan(scan => scan
        .FromAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
        .FromAssemblyOf<IUnitOfEntity>()
        .AddClasses()
        .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip)
        .AsMatchingInterface()
        .WithTransientLifetime());
```

But I get this error :

> Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating
> the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService Lifetime:
> Transient ImplementationType:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService':
> Unable to resolve service for type 'TIR.NetCore.IUnitOfEntity' while
> attempting to activate 'TIR.NetCore.BaseLoginService'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationHandlerProvider
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType:
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationHandlerProvider':
>
> Unable to resolve service for type 'TIR.NetCore.IUnitOfEntity' while
> attempting to activate 'TIR.NetCore.BaseLoginService'.) (Error while
> validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.IPolicyEvaluator Lifetime:
> Transient ImplementationType:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator': Unable to
> resolve service for type 'TIR.NetCore.IUnitOfEntity' while attempting
> to activate 'TIR.NetCore.BaseLoginService'.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FromAssemblyOf<>`, `FromAssembliesOf` - Scan the assemblies containing the provided `Type` or `Types`.

`AddClasses()` - Add all public, non-abstract classes.

`AddClasses(publicOnly)` - Add all non-abstract classes. Set publicOnly=false to add internal/private nested classes too.

`AddClass(predicate)` - Run an arbitrary action to filter which classes include. This is very useful and used extensively, as shown below.

`AddClasses(predicate, publicOnly)` - A combination of the previous two methods.

So, You can change your code like:

```
builder.Services.Scan(scan => scan
    .FromAssemblyOf<ITest>()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<ITest>())
    .UsingRegistrationStrategy(RegistrationStrategy.Skip)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    .WithTransientLifetime());
```

Comment: Hi ，If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Thanks.